# passing an event with ajax post to view with csrf token

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-views, django-csrf

I have been browsing a lot on the topic and despite all the similar solved questions I am having trouble solving this one.

I am trying to pass a simple click event to a view with the following ajax post:

```
$('#continue').click(function() {
    // var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname,
        method: 'POST',
        info: 'ReadLSL',
        data: {_token: getCookie('csrftoken')},
        success: function (data) {console.log("Acc Data is being saved to DB");}
    });
});
// GET CSRF COOKIE 

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

this is meant for the following view:

```
def myView(request):
        """..."""
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if request.info == 'ReadLSL':
                return HttpResponse("OK")
```

but I keep having a 403 error

> Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)

error.

**EDIT** changes have been made to reflect @zohaib-aslam comment

Comment: What is the purpose of `info: 'ReadLSL',`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this line

`data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: getCookie('csrftoken')},`

to

`data: {_token: getCookie('csrftoken')},`

Comment: Thank you @Zohaib-aslam. But it now returns a new 403 error instead.

Comment: then it's something on your server side code. You've to check there. What you can do is you can just place a `dd` at the beginning of method in your server-side code and you can see if request is reaching there fine or not. Then you can debug rest of your code.